# how to draw Arc in viewdidload method in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

i try to draw arc in view i use this code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,340,480);  
    UIView *ui = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [self.view addSubview:ui];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 

    CGContextAddArc(context, 50, 50, 20, 0, 30, 0); 
    //set the fill or stroke color
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);

    //fill or draw the path
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
}
```

if possible to draw arc in viewdidload method kindly guide me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to draw an arc in  view Did Load.

What you need to do is:-

1.)Add a file of type `UIView`(lets say `ArcView.h` and `ArcView.m`)in your project

2.)In `ArcView.m` file implement  `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method

3.)In this method you need to write your logic of drawing an arc or whatever you want to draw)

4.)Now the `ViewController` in which you have to show your arc lets say(`ArcViewController` is the file in which you want to show your arc)

5.)In `ArcViewController.m` file you need to do following steps:-

a.)`#import "ArcView.h"`

b.)Whenever you want to show your arc view do:-

```
ArcView *vw = [[ArcView alloc] initWithFrame:*your required frame where you want to show arc*];
vw.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:vw];
[vw release];
```

After that you will see your arc coming on your screen.

Answer (score 6):

Your views should be drawing when requested (e.g. in `drawRect:`), rather than your view controllers drawing when loaded.

So what you may want to try is creating a UIView subclass and moving the drawing code to its `drawRect:`.

Very briefly:

```
@interface MONView : UIView
@end

@implementation MONView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)frame
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    <-- now draw here -->

}

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,340,480);
    UIView * ui = [[MONView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [self.view addSubview:ui];
    [ui release];
}
```